# Non-standard function return types: Fixing Splint parse error

Tags: c, ansi-c, xc8, splint

I'm using the embedded-system XC8 C compiler (for PIC microprocessors). The following is allowed:

```
bit foo(){
    //...
}
```

but being non-standard C, the Splint static analyser gives the following error:

> Parse Error: Non-function declaration: bit :
>   "--------------------------------------"
>                  int.

And the file/line of the error is the function prototype in the respective .h file.

How can I fix this so Splint can analyse the rest of the file(s)? I think there might be two ways:

1. I think I remember seeing a flag which can be passed to Splint via CLI which tells it to substitute a given non-standard type to a standard type (e.g. bit to unsigned char) but I can't seem to find it at all now!
2. Also, perhaps there is an alternative way to write the c code that satisfies ANSI-C requirements while also still allowing XC8 to interpret the return type as `bit`?

***Progress:***

I found the following on a forum, **but I can't find information on how to use the -D flag in the [manual](http://www.splint.org/manual/)**:

> To ignore a keyword, add -Dnonstandardkeyword= to make the
>   preprocessor eliminate it

And

> use -Dspecialtype=int to make a custom type parse as an int.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no option for the analysis program to do the substitution, you can of course do it using the preprocessor.

Have something like:

```
#if defined RUNNING_SPLINT
#define bit unsigned char
#endif
```

in e.g. a header that you make sure is included everywhere, `enter code here`and make sure you define the pre-processor symbol `RUNNING_SPLINT` when Splint sees the code. It has a `-D` flag for this.

Answer (score 0):

It was in the FAQ:

http://www.splint.org/faq.html

To quote it:

> 16.I develop code on an embedded system with a compiler that uses nonstandard key words and data types. I would like to run Splint on my
>   code but these nonstandard keywords cause parse errors. What should I
>   do?
>
> You can often use -D to solve this problem.
>
> If you just want to ignore a keyword, you can add
>   -Dnonstandardkeyword= to make the preprocessor eliminate the keyword, where nonstandardkeyword is the name of the keyword. Similarly, you
>   can use -Dspecialtype=int to make a custom type parse as an int.