# Splint: substitute non-standard type `bit` with `unsigned char`

Tags: c, types, splint

(This is an extension to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986996/non-standard-function-return-types-fixing-splint-parse-error)). I'm using Splint in Windows CLI.

The XC8 embedded C compiler has a custom type `bit`. To get Splint to parse, I can pass to it the CLI option:

```
-Dbit=char
```

However I need it to replace `bit` with `unsigned char`. The space character is a problem. How can I modify the above flag?

Comment: Surrounding the argument with double quotes should work. Do you any other tools like *make* or batch files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the shell, not `splint`, which processes the quotes and escapes in command-line arguments. Any result where the shell ends up treating the whole string `-Dbit=unsigned char` as a single argument suffices, e.g., put quotes around the whole thing.

(edit: Actually, in case of Windows it may in some cases be something other than the shell that processes the quotes and escapes, but never-the-less putting double quotes around the whole thing should work.)

Comment: Thanks. From your answer I realised that there's a difference between the flag on the CLI and the same flag in the config file (splint.rc) - they need to be formatted differently.